# Asymptotic Behavior of an Entire Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $b\in\mathbb{N}\geq2$
 , $a\in\left\{ 1,2,...,b-1\right\}$ 
 , and let:

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{e^{2\pi ix}-1}{\pi ix\alpha}\frac{1}{\alpha-1}+\frac{e^{2\pi ix}-1}{\pi ix\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}\alpha^{n}}{x^{2}-n^{2}}$$

where $\alpha=e^{2\pi i\frac{a}{b}}$.

As defined, it can be shown that $f\left(z\right)$ is an entire function; moreover, $f\left(z\right)$ has no zeroes on the real line. My concern at present is the limiting behavior of this function on the real line. Empirical evidence strongly suggests that:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\alpha^{x-1}}=1$$

and that:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left|f\left(x\right)-\alpha^{x-1}\right|=0$$

This has been bugging me in my research, so, I was wondering if anyone had an idea as to how one might go about justifying either or both of these assertions rigorously.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried just plugging $\infty $ in for x?  It shouldn't be that hard to algebraically find out if these limits you propose are correct or not.  The first limit you propose seems to be valid, in my opinion.  Also, is f not also a function of a and b?  You might want to amend this to be $f(x,a,b) = ... $

Comment: If it only it was so simple as plugging in x = ∞. The $\frac{e^{2\pi ix}-1}{\pi ix\alpha^{x}}$ term dies a very slow death to 0 as x —> ∞; on the other hand, the summand tends to the non-convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{n}$ as x —> ∞. I don't believe it is possible (or legal) to evaluate the x limit on the series term by term.

Comment: Why do you think it is true, and where does your function come from ?

Comment: This function comes from a (hopefully) novel method I have developed for tackling the issue of fractional differentiation. As for why I think it is true:

1) The heuristics I've been using strongly suggest that it is true (it makes intuitive sense;

2) The graphs of the quotients and differences of the two functions converge with extreme rapidity to the desired value.

3) The fourier transforms of the functions are markedly similar

Comment: @MCS sry what I really  meant is that it is not true, because of the poles at $x = \pm n$, but maybe you meant $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n+1/2)$ or something like that

Comment: There ARE NO POLES. The x = +/- n poles are cancelled out by the zeroes of $1-e^{2\pi ix}$ at those points.

Answer (score 1):

Note : I didn't solve the question, if someone does I'll delete this

---

in the same way that $\pi \cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^2-n^2}= \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{z-n}$

(show that $\pi \cot(\pi z)-(\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{z-n})$ is a bounded entire function, and using [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)))

you have for $0 \le a/b \le 1$ :
 $$\frac{e^{2i \pi a z / b}}{e^{2i \pi z}-1} = C+\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{e^{2i \pi a n / b}}{z-n}$$

for some $C$.

And your function $f(z),z \in \mathbb{C}$ isn't entire, but [meromorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function).

Comment: And I didn't solve the question, since what I wrote works for $\sum_{n \ge 1 }\frac{\cos(2 \pi a n/b)}{z^2-n^2}$ but not for $\sum_{n \ge 1 }\frac{e^{2 i\pi a n/b}}{z^2-n^2}$ as the OP wants. This last series needs the gamma function, something like $e^{2i \pi az/b} \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$

Comment: Yes, I've already found representations for the function in terms of the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function (the so-called "digamma" function, $\psi$):  $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1-e^{2\pi ix}}{2\pi ib\alpha}\sum_{n=1}^{b-1}\alpha^{n}\psi\left(\frac{x+n}{b}\right)$ Are there any useful asymptotics for $\psi$ that could resolve the issue?

Comment: Oh! I just found an asymptotic: $\psi\left(x+1\right)\sim\ln x+\frac{1}{2x}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{-2}\right)$. Let's see if this might resolve the issue...

Comment: @MCS as $x \to + \infty$ (or $Re(z)\to + \infty$), not as $x \to - \infty$ where $\psi(x)$ has many poles

Comment: Whoops. Typed up the wrong formula for f in terms of psi. It's close enough though—what with the symmetry and all.

And yes, it's the limit as x goes to positive infinity.